# How can I modify/edit a message in a local folder of Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, plugins, text-editing

I have migrated from Outlook to Thunderbird. In Outlook I have many folders with notes. Notes migrated to Thunderbird as messages. Now I want to edit some of the notes with additional/changed info.

The only solution that I have found is to use as new message. Make my changes. And replace the old message/note with the new from the draft folder. This is very difficult. Is there a simpler solution. For example with a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The options are

- Use an add-on like [HeaderToolsLite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/header-tools-lite/)
- Move message to Drafts folder and edit it
- Edit the message store directly/offline (not what I recommend)

Please see [mozillaZine: Edit a stored message](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Edit_a_stored_message) for a good and rather official overview. As you can see it recommends the add-on [HeaderToolsLite](http://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/headertoolslite-en.html) which is [actively developed](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=2300561) and [available on addons.mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/header-tools-lite/).

Answer (score 0):

You can drag it into the drafts folder, then when you open it there is an edit button that will allow you to edit it. Then you can save it and drag it back to the original folder.